# Cordova Camera direction not working in Windows 10 Ionic app

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, windows-10

we are implementing ionic 1 application in windows 10 tablet. Project requirement mostly depends on capturing and saving image. I tried to set cordova camera in backface direction in options when opening camera in Tablet mode. But that seems not working. Please find the sample code snippet

```
          var options = {
            quality: 100,
            destinationType: 0,
            sourceType: 1,
            allowEdit: false,
            encodingType: 0,
            targetWidth: 310,
            targetHeight: 276,
            saveToPhotoAlbum: false,
            cameraDirection: 0
        };

        $cordovaCamera.getPicture(options).then(function (imageData) {             
        // Process image data
     });
```

I have no idea what may be the issue. It will be more helpful if anyone helps on this issue.

Answer (score 0):

The `cameraDirection` option was ignored from Windows 7/8 in `cordova-plugin-camera` plugin. By default the camera plugin will launch the camera with default options.

Quirks : https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-camera#windows-phone-7-and-8-quirks
Issue link for windows 10 : https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-12503

Seems that issue is not yet fixed by Cordova.